# Loading a form on to a panel in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have a Windows Form called `Form 3`.

- `Form 3` has a `side panel`(left) and a `child-form panel`(right)
- The `side panel` has an `Exam Scheduler` button which loads `Form 5` on to the `child-form panel.`

[image]

How should I code the button inside `Form 5`, so it could load another form on to the `child-form panel`?

Could someone please suggest me a YouTube video or any other site that teaches how to do this.

Comment: Can you dynamically create the form and assign the panels handle to the parent property of the form.

Comment: Why would you ask for help here for a resource ("any other site") that isn't here? I don't get it. Why not let someone here help you directly?

Comment: @Jazimov  I just assumed It might be a lot of work if someone had to explain the entire process. Since I don't have a sample code here, I wasn't sure if I should be asking for an entire answer without any effort from my side. That's why I asked for some reference. But if someone is willing to help me, I'd be thankful than ever! :)

Comment: Kushani, that's what this site is for. Yeah, some answers are a lot of work and that's why you should up-vote anyone who helps. I see an answer was posted for you--did that help? If not, please give some specific feedback and I or they will respond. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do :

- Make the ExamScheduler method public.
- Create a public property of Form3 and add a constructor in Form5 like this :

  ```
  public Form3 CallerForm { get; set; }
  public Form5(Form3 callerForm) : this()
  {
      this.CallerForm = callerForm;
  }
  ```
- Then in your Form5, you call Form3.ExamSchedulerMethod() which should look like this :

  ```
  public void ExamSchedulerMethod()
  {
      Form5 form5 = new Form5(this);
      form5.TopLevel = false;
      panel1.Controls.Add(form5);
      form5.Show();
  }
  ```

Hope that helps.